# calling routeProvider inside click event using angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there any way to call my route provider or directive inside click event using angular js.

I have a button on click of the button I need to use my directive, so based on the template url the page should navigate.

Again on click of the same button it should come to its default page.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider) {
  return $routeProvider.when('/screen1', {
    templateUrl: 'screen1.html',
    controller: 'aController'
  }).when('/screen2', {
    templateUrl: 'screen2.html',
    controller: 'bController'
  });
});

<body>
    <button id="btntog"></button>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `$location.path()`.
E.g.:

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="goTo(nextPage)">Go to {{nextPage}}</button>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>

.controller('mainCtrl', function ($location, $scope) {
    $scope.nextPage = 'screen2';
    $scope.goTo = function (page) {
        $location.path('/' + page);
        $scope.nextPage = (page === 'screen2') ? 'screen1' : 'screen2';
    };
});
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/6dJRc/)**.